# SQL : Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello Now I create  application and my task is found daily closed cashier mount

but  I have a problem in Query in Mysql when i run query 
pnpmyadmin give me this message 
Subquery returns more than 1 row

this is my sql query :

```
select tblcashieropeningbalance.Mount as COB,

   (Select tblcashiers.CashierName  from 
  tblcashiers WHERE tblcashiers.CashierID = tblcashieropeningbalance.CashierID ) as  CashierName ,

 (Select tblcashdeposit.Mount  from 
  tblcashdeposit WHERE tblcashdeposit.CashierID = tblcashieropeningbalance.CashierID ) as  CD ,

  (Select  tblbankcashiertransfer.Mount  from 
  tblbankcashiertransfer WHERE tblbankcashiertransfer.CashierID = tblcashieropeningbalance.CashierID ) as  BCT,
(Select tblsupplierrefund.Refund  from 

  tblsupplierrefund WHERE tblsupplierrefund.CashierID = tblcashieropeningbalance.CashierID ) as  SPR,

  (Select tblcustomrefund.Refund from 
  tblcustomrefund WHERE tblcustomrefund.CashierID = tblcashieropeningbalance.CashierID ) as  CUR,

 (Select  tblcustomrefund.Refund  from 
  tblcustomrefund WHERE tblcustomrefund.CashierID = tblcashieropeningbalance.CashierID ) as  CUR,

 (Select  tblcashpayments.Mount  from 
  tblcashpayments WHERE tblcashpayments.CashierID = tblcashieropeningbalance.CashierID) as  CP,


 (Select  tblcashiertransfer.Mount   from 
  tblcashiertransfer WHERE tblcashiertransfer.FromCashierID = tblcashieropeningbalance.CashierID) as  CT,

 (Select tblcashiertransfer.Mount  from 
  tblcashiertransfer WHERE tblcashiertransfer.ToCashierID = tblcashieropeningbalance.CashierID) as  CT2,

 (Select tblcustomerrefund.Refund  from 
  tblcustomerrefund WHERE tblcustomerrefund.CashierID = tblcashieropeningbalance.CashierID) as  CR,


 (Select tblcashierbanktransfer.Mount  from 
  tblcashierbanktransfer WHERE tblcashierbanktransfer.CashierID = tblcashieropeningbalance.CashierID) as  CBT,

 (Select tblexpenses.Mount  from 
  tblexpenses WHERE tblexpenses.CashierID = tblcashieropeningbalance.CashierID) as  EX,



 (Select  tblcustomespayment.Mount from 
  tblcustomespayment WHERE tblcustomespayment.CashierID = tblcashieropeningbalance.CashierID) as  CUSP

from tblcashieropeningbalance
where tblcashieropeningbalance.CashierID = '2'
and TransDate >= '2016-01-01'
and TransDate <= '2016-02-31'
```

how Can i Fix it

Comment: Are we just supposed to know which subquery ? Create a sqlfiddle please,

Comment: try to add ´LIMIT 1´ in your subquery

Comment: 1) Identify which subquery(ies) return(s) the above error message. 2) Change it/them to return a single row only. Since we do not know your data, nor your requirements, we cannot really help you any further.

Comment: Can't you remove the subqueries one by one until the error disappears?

Comment: Wouldn't rewriting these statements into one proper SELECT with reasonable JOINs (instead of selecting each column individually via subselects) be a better approach?

Comment: When you don't respond to questions asked, people close your question

Answer (score -2, accepted):

when you use subquery in your sql query, you must confirm that subquery will return 1 record only, for example if you use this query:

```
select *, (select id from internal_table where internal_table.id =
outer_table.internal_table_id) as internal_table_id from outer_table;
```

in this case you must be sure that query `(select id from internal_table where internal_table.id = outer_table.internal_table_id)` will return 1 record, if your subquery may be return more than 1 record and it isn't issue for you, you can use `limit 1` in your subquery, so for our example:

```
select *, (select id from internal_table where internal_table.id =
outer_table.internal_table_id limit 1) as internal_table_id from outer_table;
```